# Not able to install app on emulator

Tags: android, eclipse

```
[2013-07-03 10:24:58 - SimpleAndroid] Failed to install SimpleAndroid.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2013-07-03 10:24:58 - SimpleAndroid] (null)
[2013-07-03 10:24:59 - SimpleAndroid] Launch canceled!
```

I have tried all solutions as given on the web and stackover flow which includes wiping all the user data on emulator startup

I have increased the ADB connection timeout to 30000 also. My emulator and sdk are of the same version. All my packages are installed perfectly as java is working fine

**Please help someone**

[image]

Comment: Try deleting the emulator from AVD manager and recreate and try again...

Comment: already tried but no success. i have installed all these tools thrice it worked just once and stopped working.

Comment: Keep emulator running by starting it from AVD manger not from running your code. Restart eclipse keeping emulator in running state. Then run your code..

Comment: No success can windows 8 professional be causing some issue?

Answer (score 1):

Run this command on command prompt..

```
adb uninstall <package-name>
```

then

```
adb install <package-name>
```

Answer (score 0):

Close your emulator ,Got to your task manager , find **adb.exe** and **end process**. If there are multiple instances of **adb.exe** close all .

After you are done with this do a clean of the project and right click and run the project.

This should do the trick

Comment: Try restarting your PC ? Or better can you try running it on a device ?